# Generic parameter 'ResultType' error in AWSTaskCompletion()

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3, amazon-cognito

Im trying to declare a variable of type `AWSTaskCompletionSource` but I'm having `

> Generic parameter 'ResultType' could not be inferred

Please see screenshot

[image: Error]

Does this have to do with Swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, generic type needs to be explicitly declared, like this:

```
let passwordAuthenticationCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentica‌​tionDetails> = AWSTaskCompletionSource()
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked

var passwordAuthenticationCompletion : AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails> = AWSTaskCompletionSource()

It complied

Comment: @EncioPeter Great! Happy coding.

Comment: Updated the answer for other people having a similar issue.

Comment: one more thing bro, does it come with Swift 3? cause all of the tutorials I'm following use the same format as my screenshot

Comment: @EncioPeter I don't think so. It's rather an update for AWS library itself.